# Getting error while deleting records in UITABLEVIEWCONTROLLER?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, uitableview

I want to delete record from my tableviewcontroller cell.

this is my code of ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface IMSCategoryViewController : UITableViewController
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *arr;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *categoryArray;
@end
```

And This one in the implementation file.

```
#import "IMSCategoryViewController.h"
#import "IMSAppDelegate.h"
#import "Category.h"

@interface IMSCategoryViewController ()
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
}
@end

@implementation IMSCategoryViewController
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize categoryArray;
@synthesize arr;
```

and where i am performing the delete action.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSManagedObject *recordtoDelete = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [_managedObjectContext deletedObject:recordtoDelete];



        [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            //handle error here
        }

    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

OKAY So when i run this code...

it gives this type of error...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:'

Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (15) must be equal
to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (15), plus or minus
the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus 
or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the deleteObject: method, not the deletedObjects property which returns a NSSet.

Comment: it give this when i use this method


Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (15) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (15), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: You can remove [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] as the object that method returns is not being assigned to anything.  To address the error, put your deleteRowsAtIndexPaths call between an update block, like so:  

`[tableView beginUpdates];  

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];  

[tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: same error i have deleted thet line and update my code with this one